# How to correctly develop this with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

Hi this is my first question and I'm not really sure how to formulate it properly but here it goes:

I have this piece of code that correctly populates my container:

```
<div class="container" > 
         <div class="row" id="bets" ng-app="betsApp" ng-controller="betsController">
            <div ng-repeat="bet in betsList" class="item col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <a href="pages/match.html">
                <p id="timer"></p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/800x600" class="img-matchs img-responsive"></img>
              </a>
              <br></br>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

It creates a grid of images each one representing a match/bet. Now I got to the part when the user clicks on one image and I have to redirect him/her to the match page, which I already developed and I want to complete with the data regarding that particular match, using Angular of course.
My question is: How is the best way to approach this? I've been reading about Angular routing and UI-Routing (which, if I'm not mistaken, applies to one view, which I'm not using). This is the main doubt on my design.

Here's the code for the main app:

```
angular.module('betsApp', [
  'betsApp.controller'
]);
```

And the controller:

```
angular.module('betsApp.controller', []).
controller('betsController', function($scope) {

    $scope.betsList = //get the betsList 

});
```

If there is another (simplier, faster) way to do this I'm open to suggestions. Hope I was clear enough.

EDIT: If you could provide a coded example that would be the best.

Answer (score 0):

Using routes sounds perfectly fine. You would be making this feature you describe a one-page web app, which has several advantages, the biggest of which is speed. Without synchronous reloads of js, css, images, etc. the user experience would be nice and snappy.

You mention that you don't "have" a view, but it should be trivial to adapt your code to use one. The docs on this are relatively friendly.

EDIT

I'm assuming you have a way of having the page load the details of the bet/match view via AJAX. If you haven't designed the back end for that, this will be a larger investment in time. But it's a great pattern to learn.

Comment: Back-ender currently working on that.
Tried to build it with routes following an example but I don't quite get it. I think my problem lies in this
<a href="pages/match.html">

Comment: Yeah, exactly right. Read up on "URL fragments". Essentially you're going to write links that go to "bookmarks" within the same page, although ng-route will manage this so it looks to the user like they're switching pages. A more paradigmatic link would look like `<a href="#match/123"> where 123 is the id of the match you want to display.